# flask-restplus /flask-restx automatically add 401 response to Swagger docs if authentication is on

Tags: flask, flask-restplus, flask-restx

As the title mentions, I would like to have a `@api.response(401, 'Unauthenticated')` response added to the documentation of *all* APIs which require authentication.

`flask-resplus/restx` displays a lock icon, so the user should expect a `401` if not authenticated, but I would like this response to be explicit *without* having to explicitly write that decorator on every method or resource.

Is this possible with some global setting?

Answer (score 2):

+1 on that. I'm facing a somewhat similar challenge.
Also opened [this issue](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/issues/307) on their GitHub repo with hopes to get an answer.
Would be awesome if someone could suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to have a special decorator for it.
you just need the following code in you endpoints **init**.py file. Swagger will automatically support authorization and will through 401 with any decorator.

```
from flask_restx import Api
blueprint = Blueprint("api", __name__)
authorizations = {
    "Authorization": {
        "description": "Inputs: Bearer \\<jwtToken\\>",
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "header",
        "name": "Authorization",
    }
}

api = Api(
    blueprint,
    title="Dummy API",
    version="1.0",
    authorizations=authorizations,
    security="Authorization",
)
```

Comment: I am already doing this. I still need to specify that a 401 is possible in each and every endpoint